# Past in the next empty row from specific range in the Google SpreadSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to past in the next available space from A:G.

```
function test() {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  sheet1.getRange("A1:G1").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true}); }
```

If my cell "I6" isn't empty i'd have this result:

[Image with an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxZqX.png)